# Does $\lim_{x\to 0} x^nf(x^{-1})=0$ imply that $N<f (x^{-1})<M$ for some $N,M$?

Tags: limits

Does $\lim_{x\to 0} x^nf(x^{-1})=0$ imply that $N<f (x^{-1})<M$ for some $N,M$?

---

I know that if $N<f(x^{-1})<M\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0} x^nf(x^{-1})=0$.

What I want to know is if it works the other way around too, in other words, whether
$$N<f(x^{-1})<M \iff \lim_{x\to 0} x^nf(x^{-1})=0.$$

I don't really know where to start the proof.

---

Original limit was 
$$\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{f(u)}{u^n}=0$$
And I arrived at the limit in question by leting $\frac{1}{u}=x$.

$f(u)$ is continuous.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$.  Then, $f(x^{-1})=\frac1x$.  Clearly $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ fails to exist.  But for $n>1$, $\lim_{x\to0}x^nf(x^{-1})=0$.

Comment: Even if $f(x)$ is bounded, it is not necessarily true that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^{-1})$ exists. For example, $f(x)=\sin(x).$

Comment: I meant that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^{-1})$ does exist when $f(x)=\sin x.$ And you've answered my question - you don't want $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^{-1})<M,$ you want $\limsup_{x\to 0}\left|f(x^{-1})\right|<M.$

Comment: @Sebastijo Even after the changes, it's false in both directions.

Comment: @Sebastijo What on earth are you talking about?  If $f(x^{-1})$ is bounded on an open interval around $0$, then clearly for $n>0$, $\lim_{x\to0}x^nf(x^{-1})=0$.  However, if $\lim_{x\to 0}x^nf(x^{-1})=0$, we cannot infer that $f(x^{-1})$ is bounded as shown by the example $n>1$, $f(x)=x$.  End of story.

Comment: No. Not only does it not imply that $f(\dfrac{1}{x})$ is bounded it does not mean that $lim_{x\to 0} f(\dfrac{1}{x})$ is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in the other direction. Take any even $n$ and $f(x)=-e^{|x|}$.
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-e^{1/|x|}\right)=-\infty\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-x^ne^{1/|x|}\right)=-\infty $$

Answer (score 2):

If you try $n=2$ and $f(x)=x$, you are asking if $x\to0$ implies $\tfrac1x\to0$.